# How to embedded existing web pages into ExtJS frames?

Tags: extjs

How to embedded existing web pages into ExtJS frames?

I already have some web pages (written by html+css+jquery) and i want to embedded those webpages into the ExtJS frame (e.g. left panel, header and body).

Any idea how to implement it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed HTML into an `Ext.Panel` in a few ways as described [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Panel):

- With `autoLoad`
- With `html`
- With `contentEL`